# Removing svn files and directories

Tags: linux, svn

I have to write a script which only removes the svn checked out files. It's like undoing a svn checkout.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to remove all the .svn folders ?

Comment: In future it would be better if you could provide a better explanation as to your intent.

Comment: @Kev working with clients at times it is very difficult to explain intentions in few words....its more like i want to make a clean un-installation of something...like deleting databases i have created and clean up whatever code I have downloaded...

Comment: If `rm -rf myWorkingDir` is not sufficient, then you're contaminating your working directory and should stop doing that immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a better way to do this.

```
svn list | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 1):

Every file `foobar` that is *checked out* in an SVN *working copy* has a copy of itself saved in the file `.svn/text-base/foobar.svn-base`. Getting this list of files, you can get the list of *checked out* files.

```
ls .svn/text-base/ | sed 's/\.svn-base$//' | xargs rm
```

Now, to make it recursive, you use find, and a bit more complex `sed`

```
find -wholename '*/.svn/text-base/*.svn-base' | sed 's/\/\.svn\/text-base\/\(.*\)\.svn-base$/\/\1/' | xargs rm
```

But in the end, I'm really wondering what you are trying to achieve ... Did the OP really understand the meaning of *checked out* in the SVN meaning?

Comment: Or you could parse the output of `svn status -v`, perhaps with the XML option.

Comment: thanks a lot both of u...got it done using...svn status -v | cut -d' ' -f28 | sed 's/^\./\.svn/' | cut -d/ -f1 | uniq | xargs rm -rf....though i am not very happy with cutting the 28th column...there shud be a better way...but it works for now...

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -name "FILE-TO-FIND" -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Comment: There's a space missing before `-exec` but using `rm -r` defeats any benefits of using `find` anyhow.